# Link styles not working on all links, only some

Tags: html, css, styles

http://pastebin.com/mYk8M038 here is what I have so far... I think it may be something to do with the div's... BUT that doesn't explain why my Email me link hover effect is working but the links to soundcloud, linked in etc dont? Would anyone be able to shed light on how I can apply my link styles to anything on the page, regardless of the div it is in?

Comment: for examples please try http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: after the soundcloud link, you're opening another <p> instead of closing the previous one. Don't know if that is the issue though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/pxq75/1/ works fine here. Added in a closing </p> you missed

Comment: As I see it on jsfiddle, it seems to work fine. LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/YCqCw/

Comment: I pasted it into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuP4G/), and it seems to work just fine? Can you further explain the problem?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the quick replies. The issue is around the transition effect, as you can see for the top 3 links and the links in the main body (soundcloud, etc) do not use the transition effect, only the email me link does? But The style sheet doesn't specify in which div the link styles should apply to?

Comment: Can you confirm if the transition effect works on your systems? As this is the issue I am having, the transition effect only seems to be working on the email me link, and no others.

Comment: Did you close the </p> as in my example I linked to? All the transitions work fine there.

Comment: Yes, I have closed the <P>, thanks for spotting that, I still cant see the transition effects on the screen, BUT when I remove the 'http://' from the links it seems to work, does anyone have an idea as to why this is the case? I am under the assumption that I need to http:// within the link or it classes it as a 'local' link? Any ways round this at all? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems to work fine,

Is there another style sheet that is maybe causing conflict?

try adding the important tag in your css.

```
p { color: #ff0000 !important; }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

it works fine here,  I recommend you to use tools like firebug for mozilla firefox that will help you a lot to fix the CSS, see js erros, console, trafic, etc

good luck